# Chart cumulative percentage by year in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data that looks like this:

```
 items_by_year = { 
     2004: 10352,
     2005: 15125,
     2006: 8989 ...
 }
```

I'm drawing a chart of the cumulative percentage by year in matplotlib like this:

```
# Get cumulative count. Ugh!
new_dict = {}
for year in items_by_year:
    sum_of_items += items_by_year[year]
    new_dict[year] = items_by_year[year]
    for y in items_by_year:
        if y < year:
            new_dict[year] += items_by_year[y]

# Calculate cumulative percentage.
temp_data = []
for year in new_dict:
    temp_data.append((year.year, (new_dict[year] / sum_of_items) * 100))

# Sort array by year. 
data = sorted(temp_data, key=lambda x: x[0])
x = [date for (date, value) in data]
y = [value for (date, value) in data]

# Draw chart. 
fig = plt.figure()
graph = fig.add_subplot(111)
graph.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I think there must be a way to make this code nicer, but any suggestions would be very gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simpler way is to just use `plt.hist()` function with it's parameters `cumulative` and `normed`! The value `normed=True` means percentages and `cumulative=1` means exactly what you need. The only point: `plt.hist()` takes unbinned list, in a form like

`[2004, 2004, 2004, ..., 2006, 2006]`

So to get your data to this form, I use this kind of transformation (but this step may be unnessesary for you if you already have this raw data before reducing it to what you posted):

```
items_by_year = { 
 2004: 10352,
 2005: 15125,
 2006: 8989,
 2007: 1500,
 2008: 10000
}
years = sorted(items_by_year.keys())
to_hist = []
for year in items_by_year:
    to_hist.extend([year]*items_by_year[year])
```

If you already have this data, everything you need is:

```
plt.hist(to_hist, cumulative=1, normed=True, bins=years+[max(years)+1])
plt.xticks([i+0.5 for i in years], years)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**One more addition:** you can just as well draw *reverse* cumulative distribution (that is, percentage of events *after* the given year), simply by passing `cumulative = -1`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following will minimize the time spent in the loop. Binding the list of sorted keys will save time and make your code read more clearly. There's no need for the conditional used by user1866935; you have to initialize sum_of_items anyway.

```
cumulative = {}
sum_of_items = 0
years = sorted(items_by_year) # bind this to plot x values
for year in sorted(items_by_year):
    sum_of_items += items_by_year[year]
    cumulative[year] = sum_of_items
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(years, [cumulative[year]/sum_of_items for year in years])
fig.show()
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know you could use `sorted` like that with dictionaries.

Comment: It's not so much that you can use a dictionary with `sorted`; it' as much as that you can iterate across a dictionary. Sorted() takes any iterator. You can explore methods of a dictionary `d={'a':1}`  using `dir(d)`. The loop `for k in d:` iterates over keys. You can also iterate over keys and values: `for k, v in d:`. The method `__iter__` produces a iterator across the keys. The method `iteritems` produces an iterator across `(k, v)` tuples.

Answer (score 0):

That is much faster when calculating cumulative since you avoid looping over your dict again and again. You can measure the time using something like:

```
import timeit
start = timeit.timeit()
first=True
years=sorted(items_by_year.keys())
for year in years:
    sum_of_items += items_by_year[year]
    if first:
      new_dict[year]=items_by_year[year]
      first=False
    else:
        new_dict[year]=items_by_year[year]+new_dict[year-1]
end = timeit.timeit()
print end - start
```

For 43 entries your code ran on my machine in 0.000481843948364 secs and that one runs in 2.59876251221e-05

Hope I helped

Comment: I don't think that code will work at all though! `items_by_year` is a dict, so we can't guarantee the order of the keys.

Comment: did you try it and it crashed? Because it worked for me even with shuffled keys.

Comment: anyway I edited the code so you can loop over the sorted keys using a list.Again it will be faster even if you have to sort the keys once at the begining

Comment: Works with the addition `years=sorted(items_by_year.keys())`. Still think `first=True` is in the wrong place though!

Comment: as BBrown mentioned you don't have to use the condition at all. I just put it there so I can have it in the timer